# Onclick Button open a new Window only with Image inside

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and I've read a lot of answers, but none of them worked for me.
I have a button with a `Click` method. When I click on it I want my program to show a new Window, only with an image inside, which URL is previously given. Can you show me the simplest way to create such `onclick` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will start you up:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.Show();

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.ImageLocation = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    pb.Size = form.Size;
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

    form.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```